# Split the string and bring it to new line if string contains "<br>" and the string values are retrieved from a single column of a database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Split the string and bring it to new line if string contains "
" and the string values are retrieved from a single column of a database using LinqDataSource.
eg:
if string in the column is...
1) Address 1: this is addess1 < br> 2) Address 2: this is addres2

The required output is :

1) Address 1: this is addess1

2) Address 2: this is addres2

Comment: i mean if string contains "< br>"

Comment: You could use String.split():  http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Comment: also, should use the self closing <br />, that should do the job by itself I guess.

Comment: Did you try searching r do you just want SO to do your homework for you? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Replace function.

```
text.Replace("<br>", "\n");
```

This will replace your break-line with a new-line. Therefore you
wouldn't even need the split command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want really split that, you can use the following

```
var stri = "1) Address 1: this is addess1 <br> 2) Address 2: this is addres2";
var addOne = stri.Split('<')[0];
var addtwo = stri.Split('<')[1].Split('>')[1];
```

How ever as @Philipp M. mentioned, you can use Replace to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print a new line where there is a  `<br>` you could simple replace it like so:

```
string example = "this is addess1 <br> this is address2";
string result = example.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine);
```